# Angular Material: Parent height not adjusting to child height

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="product_details_container" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="15px">

<mat-card fxFlex="30" fxFlex.xs="100" class="image_container">
    <img mat-card-image src="../../../assets/img/img1.jpg" alt="">
    <mat-card-header >
        <img mat-card-avatar>
        <mat-card-title>The Silver Dress</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Available in silver and gold.</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>        
</mat-card>

<mat-card fxFlex="40" class="" class="product_details">

    <mat-card-header fxLayout.xs="column">
        <mat-card-title class="contact_us">
            Buy Now. Contact us today using the following:
        </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content >
        <button  mat-button>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="facebookIcon"></mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button  mat-button>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="linkedinIcon"></mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button  mat-button>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="twitterIcon"></mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button  mat-button>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="instagramIcon"></mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button  mat-button>
            <mat-icon>email</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-card-content>

    <mat-card-header >
        <mat-card-title>
            Product Description
        </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content>
            Acne Studios's sky-blue and white check Albany short-sleeved shirt is made from a lightweight textured cotton and linen-blend
        to an oversized fit with classic elements. The defined shape is softened with a box-pleat at the back and a curved hem. Fits
        true to size. Shown here with Marni Point-collar zip-through jacket , Bottega Veneta Straight-leg chino trousers and Prada
        Low-top Velcro trainers. Product number: 1191635
    </mat-card-content>

    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>
            Product Details
        </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header >

    <mat-card-content>                    
        <mat-list fxFlex="70">
            <mat-list-item> 50% Cotton </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item> Dry Clean </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item> Blue, Black </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>

        <mat-card fxFlex="30" class="product_price mat-elevation-z0">
            <mat-card-title>  Price </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content> R450 </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

CSS code for the component:

```
.product_details_container {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 70px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;

.image_container {
    // background-color: green;
}

.product_details {
    background-color: green;

    mat-card-header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 234, 234);
        mat-card-title {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
        }
        .contact_us {
            color: rgb(196, 127, 127);
            // background-color: red;
        }
    }
    mat-card-content {
        color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        line-height: 25px;
        mat-list {
            mat-list-item {
                color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
        }
        button {
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
        .product_price {
            padding: 0;
            mat-card-title {
                color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 15px;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }
            mat-card-content {
                color: green;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bolder;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The code above is giving the output depicted in the picture below:

[image]

My problem is that I can't seem to get the height of the green mat-card to adjust to its contents with something like `height: auto;` Could you please assist me on what I could potentially be doing wrong or maybe suggest a better way I can achieve the required behavior. Also it worth mentioning that on desktop the height adjusts well, its only on mobile that its failing to do this. If I hard code the height, it works but that is not desirable at this moment. There is no CSS applied to the class governing this mat-card.

**Edited .product_details mat-card**

```
<mat-card fxFlex="40" class="" class="product_details">
     <mat-card-header >
        <mat-card-title>
            Product Description
        </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content>
            Acne Studios's sky-blue and white check Albany short-sleeved shirt is made from a lightweight textured cotton and linen-blend
        to an oversized fit with classic elements. The defined shape is softened with a box-pleat at the back and a curved hem. Fits
        true to size. Shown here with Marni Point-collar zip-through jacket , Bottega Veneta Straight-leg chino trousers and Prada
        Low-top Velcro trainers. Product number: 1191635
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: I just need you to be specific on one point : are you seeking help for the content of the card, or for what's after the card ? Also, please post your component's css

Comment: I need help with the card. I want the card height to increase with the content. Let me post the css of the component

Comment: Okay I'll make an answer anyways

Answer (score 1):

First things first : you have two cards, recognizable by the classes `image_container` and `product_details`. I'll call them respectively IC and PD cards.

in your IC card, you have an image with the `mat-card-image` **before** the `mat-card-header`. I don't know how Material handles the inside of a card, but if it's block-displayed, HTML flow do matter. You should put it after.

In your PD card, you have 3 `mat-card-header` and 3 `mat-card-content`. You should not have that either. You can chose to make other cards, or handle the display in your card, but you should **not** use the attributes several times in the same card.

Try those two solutions and tell me how it works !

PS : I see no issue with your CSS, you don't touch the flow, only the style of your card/font, so it's okay for this part

Comment: So if I understand you well, are you trying to say I cannot nest mat-cards?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. You can nest cards as much as you want. What I'm saying is that a card should have only 1 `mat-card-header` and only 1 `mat-card-content`, and you should respect the order in which you write them.

Comment: Okay. However, I removed two of the mat-cards in PD and left only one but still I keep getting the same issue, height not growing.

Comment: What do you mean you removed two mat-cards : 2 `mat-card-header`, 2 `mat-card-content` ?

Comment: excuse me, yes two 2 mat-card-header and 2 mat-card-content

Comment: No problem, could you post your new code and a picture if you can ?

Comment: I added the new edited .product_detail mat-card. the out put i similar to the one in the picture just without the the removed content

Comment: Try surrounding your text inside a `div` or a `p` and let me know the result

Comment: Tried both still no change

Comment: Well [in this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-q8jw7a?file=app/app.component.html) I see it working ... My guess is that your fxFlex is destroying it. Try deleting it to see if it works

Comment: Matter of fact I just added fxFlex.xs="100" to PD and it started working. Its now taking the height of the contents. If you have an explanation for this that would help me understand fxFlex further. But thank you for walking with me to the solution

Comment: The explanation is about the display of your component : flex is a new type of layout, and can be tricky to master. See it as a float : if used wrong, it can get your HTML out of the document flow. [Here is another StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-aadt7f?file=app/app.component.html) with the flex working, if you want to take a look. And no problem, that's why we're here !